# REST API client implementation, what is the best practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, bridge

I am working on an HTTP Client SDK where I implemented the bridge pattern, the architecture looks like this:

[image]

The reasoning for this is that I can have multiple types of bodies and HTTP methods to implement for each type of Message, so with this I believed I would reduce the amount of classes I would create.

Something that I've noticed and has bothered me a lot is in the SMS request portion I am repeating a lot of the RestTemplate code to send the submits example:

```java
    @Override
        public AdvancedSmsResponse postMessage() {
            super.httpHeaders.set("Authorization", super.authorization.toBase64());
            super.httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            super.httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(smsAdvanced, httpHeaders);
            try{
                ResponseEntity<AdvancedSmsResponse> response = super.requestRestTemplate.exchange(getUrlHost(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, AdvancedSmsResponse.class);
                objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
                String smsResponseLog = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getBody());
                super.LOGGER.info( "\n" + response.getStatusCode() + "\n" + smsResponseLog);
                return response.getBody();
            }catch (HttpStatusCodeException | JsonProcessingException e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getDeliveryReport() {
    
            super.httpHeaders.set("Authorization", super.authorization.toBase64());
            super.httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            super.httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, httpHeaders);
            try{
                ResponseEntity<AdvancedSmsResponse> response = super.requestRestTemplate.exchange(getUrlHost() + "/report", HttpMethod.GET, entity, AdvancedSmsResponse.class);
                objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
                String smsResponseLog = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getBody());
                super.LOGGER.info( "\n" + response.getStatusCode() + "\n" + smsResponseLog);
                return response.getBody();
            }catch (HttpStatusCodeException | JsonProcessingException e){
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Is this implementation good? And also is there is a way to avoid so much repetition for the request execution part?

Comment: The question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. however from skim reading here are some suggestions; build your `httpHeaders` with default values in parent class and then simply call it when you need headers. You can change the headers in specific method if required. The line `objectMapper.configure` doesn't need to be called from every method. Configure the `objectMapper` once in parent constructor or wherever you create it. For logging use either custom interceptor on restTemplate or aspects around methods. With these changes you are left with 2 lines in those methods.

Comment: This has helped me a lot mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to extract a method that accepts the HttpEntity, the path and the HTTP method. However, I have not seen the full set of your requests. If you have a small number of things that varies, then this simple extraction might be enough to avoid the repeating code. If you have a lot of things that vary then a builder might be the way to go.

Comment: where can I find some reading material about this builder u mentioned?

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the builder design pattern. You can learn about it here, if you don't already know it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern